# Where is the aspell private dictionary on Mac

Tags: macos, emacs, homebrew, aspell

I am using emacs on Mac Os X and I installed aspell with homebrew. I accidentally added a wrong word to my "private dictionary", but where is that dictionary? How can I open it and see what I have added in there?

I found a similar question here ([How to remove an entry from ispell private dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889006/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-ispell-private-dictionary)) but I couldn't find the directories they mentioned. I found one aspell folder at `\usr\local\Cellar\aspell\`, but I still can't find which one is the private dictionary.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/777678/104302

Answer (score 4):

Search for a file ending in `.pws` -- it will probably look something like this `.aspell.en.pws` for English.

You can also run something like this to see where everything is located -- just change the path to wherever your own `aspell` executable is located:

```
/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin/aspell --lang=en dump config
```

If you want to change things, you can create an `aspell.conf` and put it inside the `etc` folder, which should be in the same set of directories near to where the `aspell` executable is located.  I actually had to create the `etc` folder and the `aspell.conf` because the make process of a generic installation did not create that folder.  Running the above command-line will also tell you the location where `aspell` looks for the `aspell.conf` file.

Sample `aspell.conf`:  I only use Spanish and English -- the default on my setup is the latter -- borrowed (and modified from):  https://github.com/jone/dotfiles/blob/master/aspell.conf

```
# /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin/aspell --lang=en dump config

# conf (string)
#   main configuration file
# default: aspell.conf

# home-dir (string)
#   location for personal files
# default: <$HOME|./> = /Users/jone
# home-dir $HOME/Library/Preferences/aspell
home-dir /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs

# personal (string)
#   personal dictionary file name
# default: .aspell.<lang>.pws = .aspell.de_CH.pws
personal .aspell.en.pws

# conf-dir (string)
#   location of main configuration file
# default: <prefix:etc> = /usr/local/etc

# data-dir (string)
#   location of language data files
# default: <prefix:lib/aspell-0.60> = /usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60
# data-dir /usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60

# dict-alias (list)
#   create dictionary aliases

# dict-dir (string)
#   location of the main word list
# default: <data-dir> = /usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60
# dict-dir /usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60

# encoding (string)
#   encoding to expect data to be in
# default: !encoding = UTF-8

# filter (list)
#   add or removes a filter

# filter-path (list)
#   path(s) aspell looks for filters

# mode (string)
#   filter mode
# default: url
# mode tex

# extra-dicts (list)
#   extra dictionaries to use

# ignore (integer)
#   ignore words <= n chars
# default: 1

# ignore-case (boolean)
#   ignore case when checking words
# default: false

# ignore-repl (boolean)
#   ignore commands to store replacement pairs
# default: false
ignore-repl false

# keyboard (string)
#   keyboard definition to use for typo analysis
# default: standard

# lang (string)
#   language code
# default: <language-tag> = de_CH

# local-data-dir (string)
#   location of local language data files
# default: <actual-dict-dir> = /usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60/

# master (string)
#   base name of the main dictionary to use
# default: <lang> = de_CH

# normalize (boolean)
#   enable Unicode normalization
# default: true

# norm-required (boolean)
#   Unicode normalization required for current lang
# default: false

# norm-form (string)
#   Unicode normalization form: none, nfd, nfc, comp
# default: nfc

# norm-strict (boolean)
#   avoid lossy conversions when normalization
# default: false

# per-conf (string)
#   personal configuration file
# default: .aspell.conf

# prefix (string)
#   prefix directory
# default: /usr/local

# repl (string)
#   replacements list file name
# default: .aspell.<lang>.prepl = .aspell.de_CH.prepl

# run-together (boolean)
#   consider run-together words legal
# default: false

# run-together-limit (integer)
#   maximum number that can be strung together
# default: 2

# run-together-min (integer)
#   minimal length of interior words
# default: 3

# save-repl (boolean)
#   save replacement pairs on save all
# default: true

# set-prefix (boolean)
#   set the prefix based on executable location
# default: true

# size (string)
#   size of the word list
# default: +60

# sug-mode (string)
#   suggestion mode
# default: normal

# sug-edit-dist (integer)
#   edit distance to use, override sug-mode default
# default: 1

# sug-typo-analysis (boolean)
#   use typo analysis, override sug-mode default
# default: true

# sug-repl-table (boolean)
#   use replacement tables, override sug-mode default
# default: true

# sug-split-char (list)
#   characters to insert when a word is split

# use-other-dicts (boolean)
#   use personal, replacement & session dictionaries
# default: true

# variety (list)
#   extra information for the word list

# warn (boolean)
#   enable warnings
# default: true

# affix-compress (boolean)
#   use affix compression when creating dictionaries
# default: false

# clean-affixes (boolean)
#   remove invalid affix flags
# default: true

# clean-words (boolean)
#   attempts to clean words so that they are valid
# default: false

# invisible-soundslike (boolean)
#   compute soundslike on demand rather than storing
# default: false

# partially-expand (boolean)
#   partially expand affixes for better suggestions
# default: false

# skip-invalid-words (boolean)
#   skip invalid words
# default: true

# validate-affixes (boolean)
#   check if affix flags are valid
# default: true

# validate-words (boolean)
#   check if words are valid
# default: true

# backup (boolean)
#   create a backup file by appending ".bak"
# default: true

# byte-offsets (boolean)
#   use byte offsets instead of character offsets
# default: false

# guess (boolean)
#   create missing root/affix combinations
# default: false

# keymapping (string)
#   keymapping for check mode: "aspell" or "ispell"
# default: aspell

# reverse (boolean)
#   reverse the order of the suggest list
# default: false

# suggest (boolean)
#   suggest possible replacements
# default: true

# time (boolean)
#   time load time and suggest time in pipe mode
# default: false


#######################################################################
#
# Filter: context
#   experimental filter for hiding delimited contexts
#
# configured as follows:

# f-context-delimiters (list)
#   context delimiters (separated by spaces)

# f-context-visible-first (boolean)
#   swaps visible and invisible text
# default: false


#######################################################################
#
# Filter: email
#   filter for skipping quoted text in email messages
#
# configured as follows:

# f-email-quote (list)
#   email quote characters

# f-email-margin (integer)
#   num chars that can appear before the quote char
# default: 10


#######################################################################
#
# Filter: html
#   filter for dealing with HTML documents
#
# configured as follows:

# f-html-check (list)
#   HTML attributes to always check

# f-html-skip (list)
#   HTML tags to always skip the contents of


#######################################################################
#
# Filter: sgml
#   filter for dealing with generic SGML/XML documents
#
# configured as follows:

# f-sgml-check (list)
#   SGML attributes to always check

# f-sgml-skip (list)
#   SGML tags to always skip the contents of


#######################################################################
#
# Filter: tex
#   filter for dealing with TeX/LaTeX documents
#
# configured as follows:

# f-tex-check-comments (boolean)
#   check TeX comments
# default: false

# f-tex-command (list)
#   TeX commands


#######################################################################
#
# Filter: texinfo
#   filter for dealing with Texinfo documents
#
# configured as follows:

# f-texinfo-ignore (list)
#   Texinfo commands to ignore the parameters of

# f-texinfo-ignore-env (list)
#   Texinfo environments to ignore
```

---

These are my notes for installing `aspell` on Windows and OSX:

```
OSX -- To dump the aspell configuration in OSX type:

# /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin/aspell --lang=en dump config

The aspell.conf goes into the .../etc directory

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

OSX -- ASPELL -- Binary

* unpack aspell-0.60.6.tar.gz

* cd over to the root directory of the unpacked source

PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin ./configure \

--prefix=$HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa

make

sudo make install

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

OSX -- ASPELL -- DICTIONARY -- English

* unpack aspell6-en-7.1-0.tar.bz2

* cd over to the root directory of the unpacked source

./configure \
--vars PATH=$PATH:/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin

make

sudo make install


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

OSX -- ASPELL -- DICTIONARY -- Spanish

* unpack aspell6-es-1.11-2.tar.bz2

* cd over to the root directory of the unpacked source

./configure \
--vars PATH=$PATH:/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin

make

sudo make install

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

Windows XP -- install:

BASE:  Aspell-0-50-3-3-Setup.exe

English:  Aspell-en-0.50-2-3.exe

Spanish:  Aspell-es-0.50-2-3.exe

Windows XP -- create an aspell.conf file at the following location:

c:/Program Files/Aspell/aspell.conf

# aspell.conf
# To dump the configuration, type into the terminal:
# "c:/Program Files/Aspell/bin/aspell.exe" --lang=en dump config

home-dir y:\.0.emacs

personal .aspell.en.pws

repl .aspell.en.prepl
```