# Emacs what is the file structure of aspell personal dictionary

Tags: emacs, aspell

I like to keep my Emacs `init.el` file under version control/synced to the web so I can pull it down from multiple computers.  I have just started using `M-x ispell` (which confusingly I'm pretty sure is invoking `aspell`, whatever the difference) to check my spelling and have begun adding to my personal dictionary of words that should not be recognized as errors.  How do I now use this dictionary on another computer?  I guess I can break the question up:

1. What files does `aspell` generate on my machine that pertain to my personal dictionary and what of these files will I need to keep under version control to use on another machine?
2. If I simply copy them to the same directory structure on another machine (potentially different OS) should I expect it to magically recognize my personal dictionary words?
3. If the answer to 2. is "No", what do I need to do/configure to tell `aspell` "hey, this is my personal dictionary file(s) you should be checking against"?

Comment: Here is a link to a semi-related thread, which discusses (in part) how to configure the aspell personal dictionary:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20013202/2112489

Answer (score 0):

Here's my config:

```
(setq ispell-personal-dictionary (concat emacs.d "ispell_dict"))
```

`emacs.d` is a string that stores site-lisp directory. On my current machine
it's `"~/Dropbox/source/site-lisp/"`.
As long as a set it up properly on different machines, the dictionary will sync.